# What do I separate in my aerator assembly?

Tags: pipe

Still trying to [connect 3 to my faucet (shown in 4-8)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/112753/68433), I unscrewed the aerator. Now what do I separate? How? Please state if I can do this by hand or need special equipment.

[image]

Comment: It doen't look like you have unscrewed the aerator. The aerator is a sieve-like piece at the very end of the faucet, where the water comes out. In your pictures 4-8, it'd be the silver colored thing at the very bottom, just below the gold nut and threaded rod.

Comment: Note that some faucets may not have a removable aerator, so you may not be able to attach a faucet-mounted filter to them. Can you post the brand and model of faucet?

Comment: @mmathis I don't know, but can try to find, the faucet's brand and model, because I didn't choose it. But how do I unscrew the silver-colored thing then, between the gold nut and threaded rod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this by myself. As shown in picture 7, just twist the bottom white part, off the golden part.

[image]